Is it possible to call functions in Python based on keypresses along with data entry?
My goal is to make a trig calculator; I am doing this for fun. I tested out the code that gives you the value for the specific trig value, e.g sin30 = 0.5, and it works. However, when I got to the part where the function is called when the user presses the enter key, it fails to be called. I was expecting for the user to input a trig value, e.g cos60 = 0.5, and then press enter, which would trigger the operation(val1) function.
import math
import cmath
import keyboard

def operation(val1):
  
  trig_func, deg_value = val1.split('(')
  deg_value = deg_value.strip(')')

  deg_value = float(deg_value)


  radians_value = math.radians(deg_value)

  trig_functions = {
    'sin': math.sin,
    'cos': math.cos,
    'tan': math.tan,
    'arcsin': math.asin,
    'arccos': math.acos,
    'arctan': math.atan
  }


  if trig_func in trig_functions:

    result = trig_functions[trig_func](radians_value)
    print(f"The result of {trig_func}({deg_value}) is: {result}")
  else:
    print("Invalid trigonometric function. Please use sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, or arctan.")

print('Follow format: trig(deg)')

val1 = input("Enter: ")

keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', lambda: operation(val1))

I tried using a while True loop at the end. However, that slowed down my program and made everything sloppier; it didn't even work and gave me the same issue as using a keyboard.add_hotkey function.

The script asks for input and waits for the user to enter something and press Enter. The program then moves to the next line, which sets up the hotkey.
But at this point, the program has finished running. It doesn't wait for another Enter press.
Instead the keybord you can use a while loop or just opeartion(val1)
while True:
    val1 = input("Enter (or 'quit'): ")
    if val1.lower() == 'quit':
        break
    operation(val1)


Your hotkey doesn't work because your code instantly terminates after you add the hotkey.  In your case however, you don't even need to use a hotkey, as the input function you call waits for the user to press enter, before continuing to execute the program. Because of this, you can just call your operation function after you ask the user for input like this:
print('Follow format: trig(deg)')
val1 = input("Enter: ")
operation(val1)

If you want this to work in a loop (not having to restart the program for each new calculation) you'd have to add a while True loop around the last three lines of code.

Oh, yeah, I didn't realize that input() already detects for the enter key to be pressed. Thank you for pointing that out; everything got resolved after I implemented that code.

If you're open to using just a loop with builtin input(), you can do as follows:
import math
def operation(value: str):
    trig_functions = {
        'sin': math.sin,
        'cos': math.cos,
        'tan': math.tan,
        'arcsin': math.asin,
        'arccos': math.acos,
        'arctan': math.atan
    }

    trig_func, deg_value = value.split('(')
    deg_value = deg_value.strip(')')

    deg_value = float(deg_value)

    radians_value = math.radians(deg_value)
    
    if trig_func in trig_functions:
        result = trig_functions[trig_func](radians_value)
        print(f"The result of {trig_func}({deg_value}) is: {result}")
    else:
        print("Invalid trigonometric function. Please use sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, or arctan.")


def main():
    running = True
    while running:
        print('Follow format: trig(deg)')
        val1 = input("Enter: ")
        if val1 == 'quit':
            running = False
        operation(val1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I'd also advise you to use:
# We check if the input begins with any of the available keys
if not any(
            map(
                lambda f_names: value.startswith(f_names),
                trig_functions.keys()
            )):
        print("Invalid trigonometric function. Please use sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, or arctan.")
        return

At the beginning of operation() instead of the IF statement you've used at it's bottom, as this way you avoid raising errors with any typos.

Thank you, however, I don't understand what the name == 'main' main() does. What is its purpose?

This segment ensures that any code inside of it will only get executed if you run that exact file. In python you can use other python files as modules And invoke them inside your main.py file. Using import is a way of compactly „copy-paste’ing” the entire module’s contents. That means, however, that any executable code That’s getting imported, will Also get executed. That IF statement is a part of the file where you can test stuff etc. Without worrying that it’ll get executed when you only wish to import a certain part of your file’s contents.
